# Using Jsoup to extract data for Android studio

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to extract data to get public ip address of each of my users so I can compare if any are currently the same. the website has no html just text that says:     {"ip":"*current ip*"} 
I try to extact this and use a toast just to test I have the info right but the toast is always blank. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    new doit().execute();
}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String ipAddressGet;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com/").get();
            ipAddressGet = doc.text();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(Homepage.this, ipAddressGet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

sorry I have never used this website before to post hopefully everything is clear. 
all the descrptions for jsoup involve HTML use but this has none so i dont know how to apply the descrptions there

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
ipAddressGet = doc.body().ownText();
```

instead of

```
ipAddressGet = doc.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com/").get();
    ipAddressGet = doc.text();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To this:

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com/").get();
    Element body = doc.body();
    ipAddressGet = body.text();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But to get and handle responses of requests to the web, use one of known libs, like Retrofit or Volley.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JSoup for this. Java can deal with it just fine:

```
private static String readStringFromURL(String requestURL) throws IOException
{
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL(requestURL).openStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
    {
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
        return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
    }
}
```

If your text is also JSON-formatted, most JSON parsing libraries also have built-in capabilities for reading from a URL.